# Set upstream between two DAGs

Tags: python, airflow

I have two python files that (proc1.py and proc2.py) that call some BaseOperator to do some processing. The workflow is something like this (simplified for readability):

```
proc1:
calculate1->calcualte2->end
def generate_proc1_dag(dag):
   run_this = BaseOperator()
   cal1 = Calculate1()
   cal1.set_upstream(run_this)
   cal2 = calcualte2()
   cal2.set_upstream(cal1)
   end = BaseOperator()
   end.set_upstream(cal2)
proc1_dag = DAG(dag_id='proc1', default_args=ARGS, schedule_interval=None)
generate_proc1_dag(proc1_dag)

proc2 (similar to proc1):
calcualteA->calcualteB->end
```

The operations from proc2.py should start afer proc1 finishes. As a result, I tried to create a new DAG (run_all.py) where I tried this:

```
def generate_run_all_dag(dag):
   run_this = BaseOperator()
   global proc1_dag
   global proc2_dag

   generate_proc1_dag(proc1_dag)
   proc1_dag.set_upstream(run_this)

   generate_proc2_dag(proc2_dag)
   proc2_dag.set_upstream(proc1_dag)

   end = BaseOperator()
   end.set_upstream(proc2_dag)

run_all_dag = DAG(...)
generate_run_all_dag(run_all_dag)
```

Firs, i am not 100% sure I can use the set_upstream the way I do in run_all.py, however, I don;t know any other way to mention that proc2 should start after proc1.

Now, when I use this, i get the following exception: airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Tried to create relationships between tasks that don't have DAGs yet. Set the DAG for at least one task  and try again

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
**NOTE:** proc1 and proc2 work independently and (if possible) no changes should be made to them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use ["ExternalTaskSensor"](https://airflow.apache.org/_modules/airflow/sensors/external_task_sensor.html) for this. So your proc2.py will contain something like this:

```
sensor = ExternalTaskSensor ( 
    task_id='proc2_sensor_task',
    external_dag_id='proc1',
    external_task_id='proc1_task_id',
    dag=dag
)

proc_2_task.set_upstream(sensor)
```

However, for this to work you'll need to define 'proc1_task_id' in proc1.py and proc_2_task in proc2.py.

I suggest you take a look a the tutorial here for instructions on how this is done: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/tutorial.html